# How add menu item's only for debug build type

Tags: android

In my build.gradle I has to build types:
-debug
-release

In my anroid app I has menu with one item:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="md.factura.app.cart.CartActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemRefresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_ac_refresh"
        android:title="@string/check_state"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Now I need to add one more menu's item **ONLY for debug build type**.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Add all menu item in the xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="md.factura.app.cart.CartActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemRefresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_ac_refresh"
        android:title="@string/check_state"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuItem1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_item_1"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_1"
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

And in your activity

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu)
    val menuItem1: MenuItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.menuItem1)

    // Use this flag to check if DEBUG
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { menuItem1?.isVisible = true }

    return true
}
```